# illegal option : and when generating signing certificate

Tags: sha1

May somebody help me tell why I got this illegal option? I used also C:/Users/myAccount

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need to put quotes around your file specification:

```
blah blah -keystore "c:\documents and settings\...keystore" blah blah
```

Otherwise it's treated as multiple arguments first `c:\documents`, then `and` (which is what's causing you grief) and so on.

In other words, by *not* quoting the path, the arguments being seen by your `keytool` program (other than the program name itself) are:

```
   -exportcert
   -alias
   androiddebugkey
   -keystore
 / C:\Documents
|  and
 \ Settings\Administrator\.android\debug.keystore
   -list
   -v
```

where the three indicated lines should really constitute a *single* argument.

Comment: @user1907521, then that would be a totally _different_ problem. The "illegal option 'and'" problem is fixed with this answer. Suggest you ask another question.

Comment: @user1907521, also feel free to upvote useful answers and accept the best - both answers to date basically say the same thing but Anton probably needs it more than I :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your `-keystore` path is being interpreted as multiple arguments. Surrounding it with double quotes (`"`) shoud help.

Comment: It sees the arguments: (1) `-keystore`, (2) `C:\Documents` (which is interpreted as the argument for `-keystore`), and (3) `and` (which is interpreted as the next option name, and it's illegal)